# Choosing AI strategy

Tags: ai, reinforcement-learning

How would I choose to design an AI that would know the rules of the game, however not know the game world before hand?

Given fx. a Sokoban game, I could teach it using Reinforcement Learning to play a map optimally. However as soon as I change the map but not the game rules, all it has learn is discarded. So what would be the tactic to make this work in the area of AIs being able to find a near optimal solution in an arbitrary board setting?

Comment: Yes I do :P I will edit this immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff the computer scientists call "Artificial Intelligence"  is quite different than what game developers mean when they speak about "Artificial Intelligence".

Neural networks and reinforced learning are a quite obscure technique when it comes to game AI (still not completely unheard of, though). Most game AIs are implemented by rule engines or [minmax tree searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax).

A rule-based AI analyzes the situation and makes decisions based on a set of preset rules (like in a platformer (`if (player is in front of me) then fire bullet` or in a 4x strategy game `if (enemy_military_power / my_military_power) < diplomatic_relationship_score) then declare war`). This usually results in an AI which can play very complex games in a way which is not really that great because it often has several glaring weaknesses a crafty player can find and exploit, but is usually at least able to entertain the player until they figured it out.

A minmax tree-search based AI checks all possible moves it could possibly make and several possible moves it could make afterwards and then picks the move order which leads to the best outcome by applying a rating function. This doesn't work well for all games. It only really works well on games without randomness or information hiding. It can also become quite computation-intense when there is a large number of possible moves. But on those games where it does work, such an AI can reach terrific AI strength on par with players with years or even decades of experience (like in Chess, for example).

Considering that Sokoban is a game where no randomness or information hiding involved and the number of possible moves at any given time is rather limited, it leads itself well to a minmax-AI. You only need to evaluate the chest-pushes the character can legally make from the positions it can currently reach without pushing a chest, because moving around usually has no consequences so it isn't actually a move. A rating function could simply look at how many chests are on a target-field. But in fact the number of moves is so small that simply brute-forcing all possible move-sequences until they either lead to a configuration you already had or to the solution might actually be viable.

Comment: I know that AI in the sense of state based search is not usually connected with game development, but I was told to ask my question here, after posting it on stackoverflow.
However as you suggest tree-search would be viable. However presented with a slightly more advanced game setting than Sokoban, where memory starts becoming an issue and tree-search is taking too long. What would a good learning technique be to solve the problem in arbitrary levels?